# Criar um filtro múltiplo com apenas um input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

No meu sistema, eu criei uma diretiva que recebe os parâmetros necessários para atualizar uma tabela, que seria essa:

```
function filtroAngularTable() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            lista: '=',
            config: '='
        },
        controller: 'PaginacaoCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/diretivas/paginacao_at_table/html/filtro.html'
    }
}
```

Através dessas informações eu posso atualizar a tabela com base no que eu digito:

```
$scope.listaOriginal = $scope.lista;
    $scope.listaFiltrada = $scope.listaOriginal;

    $scope.atualizarTabelaComFiltro = function () {

        $scope.listaFiltrada = $filter("filter")($scope.listaOriginal, {nome: $scope.filtro});
        $scope.lista = $scope.listaFiltrada;
        $scope.config.total = $scope.lista.length;
    }
```

Até aqui funciona perfeitamente, ele está filtrando pelo titulo, recebendo o ng-model "$scope.filtro" do input.

Mas a questão é: Como posso filtrar por outro campo, além do título, com o mesmo input?

Por exemplo, filtrar por nome e sobrenome usando o mesmo input.

Já tentei colocar mais um objeto no filtro, tentei colocar outra posição no objeto, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
$scope.listaFiltrada = $filter("filter")($scope.listaOriginal, {nome: $scope.filtro}, {sobrenome: $scope.filtro});
$scope.listaFiltrada = $filter("filter")($scope.listaOriginal, {nome: $scope.filtro, sobrenome: $scope.filtro});
```

Também queria fazer com que a lista dos campos que eu queira filtrar seja passada como scope da diretiva, para ficar mais dinâmico.

Estou utilizando o [Samu/angular-table](http://samu.github.io/angular-table/examples/examples.html).

**EDIÇÃO**

Esqueci de mencionar anteriormente, mas o ng-model de onde eu tiro o que filtrar está aqui:

```
<div class='ui icon input'>
     <i class='search icon'></i>
     <input placeholder='Pesquisar pelo título...' type='text' ng-model="filtro" ng-change="atualizarTabelaComFiltro()">
</div>
```

Então, como eu havia dito, eu estou utilizando o [Samu/angular-table](http://samu.github.io/angular-table/examples/examples.html). Ele apenas recebe os parâmetros de onde tirar os itens da lista e sua configuração e faz o resto basicamente sozinho, como por exemplo:

```
<table class="ui compact table" at-table at-paginated at-list="lista" at-config="config"></table>
```

Ainda não consigo ver como posso criar um input externo para atualizar a tabela com base em filtros dinâmicos.

Answer (score 0):

Eu começaria por criar o próprio **scope** da **directiva**, e passar os inputs recebidos para o scope da directiva para a tornar independente do código do controlador em que é usada.

E simplificar o código porque está uma grande confusão na declaração de variáveis, que melhora a sua leitura.

```
function filtroAngularTable() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      //filtro tem que ser um objecto por ex. {nome:"value",sobrenome:"value"}
      filtro: '=',
      lista: '=',
      config: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/diretivas/paginacao_at_table/html/filtro.html',
    link:function(scope,element,attributes) {
      //o filtro "filter" retorna um novo array com os items seleccionados.
      scope.listaFiltrada = $filter("filter")(scope.lista, scope.filtro);

      scope.config.total = scope.lista.length||scope.listaFiltrada.length;
      //não consegui compreender se queria usar a length do array original ou do filtrado
    }
  }
}
```

outra opção é usar o filtro no template do `ng-repeat`.

```
<linha ng-repeat="item in lista|filter:filtro"></linha>
```

Comment: obrigado pela sua resposta e pelos seus conselhos, mas acho que eu acabei não mostrando todos os detalhes, vou atualizar a pergunta.